# Bridging edge loops causes unwanted criss cross result

Tags: edges

I am trying to bridge two edge loops shown here:[image]

In order to make a looped face between them. When I use the bridge tool, the result ends up as this:[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? And is there an easier way to achieve a face between the two edge loops shown?

Comment: I recreated what you showed in the screenshots. Bridging loops worked fine. Your mesh likely has overlapping geometry or are not complete loops. **Do a "remove doubles" to make the loops clean before bridging them.**

Comment: Have you checked the normals?

Comment: Could you post your .blend file?

Comment: (I answered the question... though I was not 100% sure without seeing the mesh.  I could not leave a comment asking for it because my reputation was below 50.  But I was still very sure that was the answer.  It was marked as answered.  A moderator converted my answer to that comment above.)